# How can I prove that $a>b $ implies $a^n > b^n$

Tags: proof-writing

I am having trouble with understanding this proof
$a,b \geq 0$ and a and b are in ordered field
How can I prove that
$a>b$ $\implies$ ($\forall n \in \mathbb N$ $a^n > b^n$)

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** In ordered field $a>b\implies ac>bc$, for $c>0$. Now, use induction on $n$.